# The ארור of becomming a servant of servants

Tags: words, parashat-noach

In Bereshit 9:25 ארור is used to describe something of which the consequence is that Kena'an will be a eved avadim - a servant of servants - unto his brethren.

So What's the definition of ארור and in which way does becoming a servant of servants unto his bethren  is ארור?

Comment: Maybe it means 'cursed'. He is cursed in that he will be a slave. 'cursed' is the common translation. Do you have some reason to assume that this is not the translation?

Comment: Maybe it's just me - what exactly is the q? Seems like OP answered his own q in the opening.

Comment: @Oliver I didn't wanted to translate arur right away, I wanted to look at the context and found it strange that living among his bethren is the curse, I wondered why it was written this way.

Answer (score 2):

According to Rav Hirsch, the English word *curse* as in a wish that an evil fate befall one, is not correct. It is a declaration explaining the necessary fate caused by the character of Cham (and through him Canaan).

> for it is no means necessary that ארור always expresses a wish in the
>   ordinary sense of a "curse", but rather and especially here, a declaration.

Rav Hirsch explains that

> the principle that showed itself in Cham can, and may, and will never
>   be the ruling one. Raw "hot" sensuality, which has no control over
>   itself, which has lost all reserve and all respect for anything
>   spiritually high is unfit for ruling, yea for freedom, it in itself is
>   unfruitful, is ארור without progress or blessing, it bears its ruin in
>   itself.

Rav Hirsch also explains that the term עבד עבדים means the paradigm of slavery. Someone who falls under this *curse* can never become free. Thus, others can become עבדים but Canaan as the paradigm of those who submit themselves to slavery will be עבד עבדים.

> And, as a matter of fact, as ארור lies in Canaan, so that the future
>   belongs only to the pure and ennobled, but not to the coarse,
>   unrefined, so also in the social and national life, in the relation of
>   man to man and nation to nation, freedom is only achieved and retained
>   by those who can master and control themselves. Sensuality,
>   uncontrolled licentiousness, is the bait by which one is led by
>   strings into slavery. He who at all times is master of himself, who
>   can easily control giving satisfaction to the urges of his senses, he
>   cannot be bribed or enticed, for him gold cannot become golden chains;
>   he can go under, die - but he cannot become enslaved. Thus for men,
>   thus for nations.